# checking assertions in a lambda in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use assertions to show some invariants (mostly in testing)
Thus i want to write something like the following:

```
values = [ range(10) ] 
expected_values = [ range(10) ]

map (lambda x: assert x[0] == x[1] ,zip( [ run_function(i) for i in values ], expected_values))
```

If I use this with unittest.assertEqual this works perfectly fine , but if I want to write this with an assertion it just fails. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, `assert` is a statement and Pythons limited lambdas don't allow that in them. They also restrict things like `print`.

You can use a generator expression here though.

```
assert all(x[0] == x[1] for x in  zip( [run_function(i) for i in values ], expected_values))
```

I personally think that the following would be more readable

```
assert all(run_function(i) == j for i,j in zip(inputs, expected_values))
```

Comment: Here is something else you can do to actually assert: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40286356/78234

Answer (score 13):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

> Note that functions created with lambda forms cannot contain statements.

[`assert` is a statement.](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement)

So no, you cannot use the `assert` statement in a lambda expression.

Comment: No, you are not using the `assert` statement. You are achieving a similar effect by throwing the error, but that doesn't invalidate what I said.

Comment: Of course I'm hacking it - you cannot use a statement, as you said.

Answer (score 7):

Actually you can:

```
assertion_raiser = lambda: (_ for _ in ()).throw(AssertionError("My Lambda CAN raise an assertion!"))
```

Here is some validation:

```
try:
    assertion_raiser()
except AssertionError:
    print("assertion caught")
```

Comment: Interesting it doesn't look very readable though. I guess I'd rather wrap an assertion into a function or write my own assert function that allows me to put it in a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Worked in my application, which was similar:

```py
def _lambda_assert(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    def _assert(fn_out):
        if isinstance(fn_out, (list, tuple)):
            value, fail_msg = fn_out
            assert value, fail_msg
        else:
            assert fn_out  # value only
    return lambda: _assert(fn(*args, **kwargs))
    # return lambda x: _assert(fn(*args, **kwargs))  # for pytest; need dummy positional
```

---

**Usage example**:

```py
import numpy as np

def _test_precision(size, atol=1e-2):
    x = np.random.randn(size)
    y = np.random.randn(size)
    absdiff = np.abs(x - y)
    fail_msg = f"absdiff: {absdiff}; atol={atol}"
    return np.allclose(x, y, atol=atol), fail_msg

lambda_assert = _lambda_assert(_test_precision, 20, atol=1)
```

Comment: That would make erros messages harder though? As you evaluated the expression before the assert.

Comment: @Alex This is only a minimal example; the key that's shown is to effectively wrap the assertion in a callable via a local function definition - how `value` and `fail_msg` are derived is highly flexible. For example, I actually fetched both from yet another function: `value, fail_msg = _fn()`, where `_fn()` is arbitrarily complex. It was among the few things I had to craft to hack around PyTest's various requirements.

Comment: @Alex Admittedly my example wasn't very clear - updated answer

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to define a auxiliary function that raises an assert given an input boolean value:

```
def assert_(cond): assert cond

values = [ range(10) ] 
expected_values = [ range(10) ]

map (lambda x: assert_(x[0] == x[1]) ,zip( [ run_function(i) for i in values ], expected_values))
```